# Expire fragment in Rails 3 for all locales with cache digests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I am using rails 3 with cache_digests and I have a fragment cache in a template:

```
<% cache [I18n.locale,'city-list'] do %>
...
<% end %>
```

In an observer I want to expire that cache for all locales like this:

```
I18n.available_locales.each do |loc|
  ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment("#{loc}/city-list")
end
```

But obviously this won't work, because I am **missing the digest** of that fragment in the expire call.

Is there a clean way to expire this cache?

Comment: I had a similar issue, needing to cache a json response. Shared my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23783119/252799 - hopefully it is helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the answer is "No way to make cache_digests work with manual expiration", see [these](https://github.com/rails/cache_digests/issues/35) [answers](https://github.com/rails/cache_digests/issues/14) from DHH.

To work around there are two options:

1. **Tie** the key **to** some **model** and rely on the **key-based expiration**: `<% cache [I18n.locale, city, "city-list"] do %>`
2. **Skip the digest** in the cache call, and **expire manually** like showed in the question: `<% cache [I18n.locale, "city-list"], skip_digest: true do %>`

Comment: Not sure 1 works. Can you expand on it? I'd like to keep the digest but expire with digest if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<% cache "#{I18n.locale} city-list" do %>
...
<% end %>

#To clear
I18n.available_locales.each do |loc|
  ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment("#{loc} city-list")
end
```

Comment: Does not work for me. The key in expire_fragment still does not contain the digest