# Rails fragment cache not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this piece of code in view

```
<% cache("students_cache") do %>
  <% @swimming_students.each do |swimming_student| %>
    <tr class="gradeX">
      <td><%= link_to " #{swimming_student.full_name}", swimming_student %></td>
      <td><%= swimming_student.homephone %></td>          
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And I have the expire code in anther action

```
  def create
     expire_fragment("students_cache")
    @swimming_student = Swimming::Student.new(params[:swimming_student])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @swimming_student.save
        format.html { redirect_to @swimming_student, notice: 'Student was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @swimming_student, status: :created, location: @swimming_student }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @swimming_student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

end

But after I created a new student the cache was not updated.

Something is missing?

Comment: Where do you update `@swimming_students`?

Comment: @spickermann Do I have to update `@swimming_students`? Isn't `expire_fragment("students_cache")` supposed to expire cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using fragment caching with string keys, you should turn off cache digests:

```
<% cache("students_cache", skip_digest: true) do %>
```

See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445994/rails-4-0-expire-fragment-cache-expiration-not-working) for more details.